# parse.com promises - do i need to have an "error" function in each "then"?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

parse.com offers a cloud-code section so that I can write javascript code to modify my parse.com database.

I have such a cloud code function that does multiple things - say, checks if a user exists, and if the user exists saves some data in a different table and then updates the user table to reference this new table - so I would have one parse.Query that checks if the user exists, and then several `then` statements to run the update on the other table and get the user table to reference this new row.

In this scenario, am I meant to have **several** error functions (eg one for each parse.Query), or is it acceptable to have **one** error function in the very last `then` promise?

Comment: see also [Do I always need catch() at the end even if I use a reject callback in all then calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30881106/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is acceptable.

Promises are like exceptions, having an error function for each `.then` is like having a `.catch` block for each statement:

```
try{
    first();
} catch(e) {
    //handle
}
try{
    second();
} catch(e) {
    //handle
}
try{
    third();
} catch(e) {
    //handle
}
```

Often, having one catch is more natural and clearer

```
try {
   first();
   second();
   third();
} catch (e) {
    // handle error in whole flow.
}
```

Likewise with promises:

```
 first().then(second).then(third).catch(function(e){ /* handle error */});
```

Or, with implementations without catch like `Parse.Promise`:

```
 first().then(second).then(third).then(null,function(e){ /* handle error */ });
```

The flow of control would be exactly like you would expect - if `first` fails, then it'll be handled by the *first* error handler, and it will *not* execute and fulfillment callbacks in the process so:

```
Parse.promise.as(true).then(function(){
    throw new Error("Promises are throw safe and throws are rejections! funstuff");
}).then(function(){
    alert("This will never show");
}).then(function(){
    alert("This will never show either");
}).then(null,function(e){
    alert("This is the error handler!" + e.message);
}).then(function(){
   alert("Since the error was handled this will show");
});
```

Always think about the synchronous analogue when considering how promises might behave.

Comment: Apparently jQuery (and hence Parse) promise errors are not handled by an error function, unless it returns a promise. That is, the last alert will actually not fire! I have tested this with Parse Cloud Code.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev if I may suggest, use a decent promise implementation. Adding Bluebird, all you have to do is `Promise.cast` (or event just `Promise.resolve` ) your promises which would cause them to be trusted Bluebird promises giving you a much much richer, faster and more debuggable API.

Comment: Unfortunately I have limited control on that for Parse Cloud Code. However, with their curret promise API all I need to remember is to return a promise in each callback.

Comment: Here is Parse's explanation in details: http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/

Comment: Concerning using Bluebird or other external libraries - I need to see a real payoff for jumping through the whoops. Something that can't be easily achieved with the out-of-the box Parse's implementation.

Comment: @JoeBlow I swear, promises are simple - in a month if you're using promises you'll be as good at this. At their core they're much simpler than callbacks :)