# What errors do catch() and "error handler" of then(successHandler, failureHandler) detect?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning Promises so that I can understand better before I try to use Firebase. I am new and I've been reading the following in regard to `catch()`:

- [Link one](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/the-catch-method): An article with some exercises
- [Link two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881106/do-i-always-need-catch-at-the-end-even-if-i-use-a-reject-callback-in-all-then): A question in SO in regard to why we always need a `catch()` after Promise chain
- [Link three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises/24663315#24663315): A question in SO in regard to the difference of `catch()` and `then()`

From what I've read, I have taken the following conclusions:

- `catch()` is necessary at in every Promise chaining in case "unexpected exceptions" occurs. It seems like these "unexpected exceptions" **can** be detected by the `failureHandler` of my `then`. However, it cannot distinguish between "normal failure" from these types of failures. I assume that one of those "unexpected exceptions" is when you're trying to access some property of a `null` element.
- It seems like I can also do chaining of `then(successHandler, failureHandler)` and then proceed with a `catch()` block to allow finer control, as mentioned in [link two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/9060223). This is useful when I want to do something else when something fails ("normal failure" in this case, not the "unexpected exceptions") and pass the rejected Promise to the next `then` to process, thus potentially yielding very different results from the result had the failed part succeeded. I can also catch "unexpected exceptions" by using `catch()` at the end of the chain in case something failed inside my `successHandler` or `failureHandler`.

As you can see from my conclusions, I have very little understanding of what errors might occur. I mentioned `null` exception as one of the examples of "unexpected exceptions" (is this assumption even correct?). However, what other errors do `failureHandler` detect and what other "unexpected exceptions" do `catch()` detect?

I also mentioned above that *[`then`] cannot distinguish between normal failure from these types of failures*. Is that correct? If it is, why is it important?

**EDIT**

After reading some more, it seems like if a Promise is rejected on the top of the chain, the `then`s following are ignored and I immediately go to the `catch()` block. This means that my conclusion above: ***This is useful when I want to do something else when something fails and pass the rejected Promise to the next `then` to process*** is incorrect. If that is the case, if I already have a `catch()` at the end of my chain, I no longer need a `failureHandler` for each of my `then` block. However, it is mentioned in link three:

> The argument is that usually you want to catch errors in every step of
>   the processing, and that you shouldn't use it in chains. The
>   expectation is that you only have one final handler which handles all
>   errors - while, when you use the "antipattern", errors in some of the
>   then-callbacks are not handled.
>
> However, this pattern is actually very useful: When you want to handle
>   errors that happened in exactly this step, and you want to do
>   something entirely different when no error happened - i.e. when the
>   error is unrecoverable. Be aware that this is branching your control
>   flow. Of course, this is sometimes desired.

I took my conclusion that the rejected Promise will be passed to the next `then` to process because I read the above. So what does ***and you want to do something entirely different when no error happened - i.e. when the error is unrecoverable*** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description) I understand that there is no real difference between the two methods of declaring the rejection handler.

For success, it's obvious that we will get to the fulfillment handler:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('success');
  }, 300);
}).then(function(success) {
  console.log(0, success)
}, function(failure) {
  console.log(1, failure)
}).catch(function(failure) {
  console.log(2, failure)
});
```

For rejection we'll get to the first rejection handler.
When rejecting the promise:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    reject('failure');
  }, 300);
}).then(function(success) {
  console.log(0, success)
}, function(failure) {
  console.log(1, failure)
}).catch(function(failure) {
  console.log(2, failure)
});
```

When throwing an error:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw "throw";
}).then(function(success) {
  console.log(0, success)
}, function(failure) {
  console.log(1, failure)
}).catch(function(failure) {
  console.log(2, failure)
});
```

Notice how the `catch` block is being ignored because it's being chained to the promise of the first handler (fulfillment or rejection).
If we change it to reject or re-throw we'll get to the handler in the `catch`.

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw "re-throw";
}).then(function(success) {
  console.log(0, success)
}, function(failure) {
  console.log(1, failure)
  throw failure;
}).catch(function(failure) {
  console.log(2, failure)
});
```

This image, from the above link, describes it well.
[image: Image from MDN link]